# Stopping helper goroutine which waits for UDP data without freezing main goroutine in Go

Tags: multithreading, go, channel, goroutine, ticker

I have following receiver construction based on `time.Ticker`, which calls method `receive()` every given constant time interval, controlled by channels (To fetch some useful data from server).

There is a main routine with main application logic and second routine with this receiver logic (defined in `Start()` method). And there is a following problem: when I'm trying to stop receiver routine from main routine (using defined `Stop()` method) while `receive()`waits for data from UDP connection, main routine seems to freeze (I have some GUI there and it doesn't allow to interract). I don't actually understand why is this happening, beacuse channels should allow me to interract with this receiver routine. I need to stop this receiver in given point of time even if it is still waiting for UDP data and main routine should still be able to work. I would be grateful for explaination and some idea how to approach stopping this receiver without freezing main routine.

Greetings

```
type RtpReceiver struct {
    Ticker            *time.Ticker
    Interval          time.Duration
    doneCheck         chan bool
    started           bool
    // some othe fields
}

func NewRtpReceiver() *RtpReceiver {
    // some logic
    return &RtpReceiver{
        doneCheck:      make(chan bool),
        started:        false,
    }
}

func (receiver *RtpReceiver) receive() {
    _, _, _ = (*receiver.UdpCon).ReadFrom(receiver.buffer)
    // some logic
}

func (receiver *RtpReceiver) Start() {
    receiver.started = true
    receiver.Ticker = time.NewTicker(receiver.Interval)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-receiver.doneCheck:
                return
            case <-receiver.Ticker.C:
                receiver.receive()
            }
        }
    }()
}

func (receiver *RtpReceiver) Stop() {
    if receiver.started {
        receiver.doneCheck <- true
        receiver.Ticker.Stop()
        receiver.started = false
    }
}
```

Comment: `doneCheck` should probably be a Context (or at least be a channel close). You're not actually interrupting the `ReadFrom`, so I assume you are blocked sending to `doneCheck`. Show where the program is blocked and we can know for sure,

Comment: Thanks for answer. Program is blocked while trying to perform `receiver.doneCheck <- true`. It won't perform any operations after it.
You're right, closing channel solves problem. But if I need this channel open in future, is it good approach (in terms of design) to closing it in `Stop() ` and reinitialising in `Start()`, or should I rather use Context for that?

Comment: Can you set a deadline for your read operation (UDP connection) so that we don't wait forever for a server that might not respond on a reasonable amount of time?